# Parse TimeStamp token from Base64 string

Tags: c#, digital-signature, bouncycastle, asn.1

I'm trying to create XAdES-T signature. In my C# app I'm calling a "go-between" web service which takes string as input and also returns Base64 string.

In that string is encoded asn.1 schema and there somewhere should be TimeStamp Token in it. I decoded it but don't see anything understandable for me.

I have been told that I should use BouncyCastle.Asn1.Tsp.TimestampResp. But there is no suitable constructor which takes string.

I'm really lost in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out yet.

I found this code in bccrypto src folder which I downloaded from their site.

```
 private static TimeStampResp readTimeStampResp(
        Asn1InputStream input)
    {
        try
        {
            return TimeStampResp.GetInstance(input.ReadObject());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            throw new TspException("malformed timestamp response: " + e, e);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            throw new TspException("malformed timestamp response: " + e, e);
        }
    }
```

Then I just call this method like this.

```
var tsResp = readTimeStampResp(new Asn1InputStream(Convert.FromBase64String(tsRespB64)));
```